# What's wrong with my Python 3/PyQt5 code?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have this code and want to do some calculations after pressing buttons and show results in QTextEdit widget (ted). Everything works well, but if I run the program and press the button (button1) it crashes.

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot for answers!

The code is here:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'STATISTICIAN'
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        button1 = QPushButton('1D statistics', self)
        button1.setToolTip('Start calculations of 1D statistics')
        button1.move(50, 25)
        button1.resize(500,70)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click1)

        button2 = QPushButton('2D statistics', self)
        button2.setToolTip('Start calculations of 2D statistics')
        button2.move(50, 105)
        button2.resize(500,70)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

        ted = QTextEdit(self)
        ted.move(50, 250)
        ted.resize(500, 250)
        ted.setReadOnly(True)
        scrb = ted.verticalScrollBar()
        scrb.setValue(scrb.maximum())

        self.show()

    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_click1(self):
        # Reading of data from file will be here
        # Some calculations will be here
        text = 'Results are:' # There will be finally more text
        ted.insertPlainText(text) # I'm trying to show results in QTextEdit (ted)

    def on_click2(self):
        print('2D statistics')
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Include the exact error message.

Comment: There is no exact error message except: The Python has stopped working. And after it the window of program automatically closes... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ted` variable can not be accessed from `on_click1`, you must use the self instance to use it, replace `ted` with `self.ted`.

**Complete code:**

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QTextEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'STATISTICIAN'
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 600, 600)

        button1 = QPushButton('1D statistics', self)
        button1.setToolTip('Start calculations of 1D statistics')
        button1.move(50, 25)
        button1.resize(500,70)
        button1.clicked.connect(self.on_click1)

        button2 = QPushButton('2D statistics', self)
        button2.setToolTip('Start calculations of 2D statistics')
        button2.move(50, 105)
        button2.resize(500,70)
        button2.clicked.connect(self.on_click2)

        self.ted = QTextEdit(self)
        self.ted.move(50, 250)
        self.ted.resize(500, 250)
        self.ted.setReadOnly(True)
        scrb = self.ted.verticalScrollBar()
        scrb.setValue(scrb.maximum())

        self.show()

    def on_click1(self):
        # Reading of data from file will be here
        # Some calculations will be here
        text = 'Results are:' # There will be finally more text
        self.ted.insertPlainText(text) # I'm trying to show results in QTextEdit (ted)

    def on_click2(self):
        print('2D statistics')
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It works absolutely perfect. Thanks a lot!!! You helped me so much... :-)))